# Some limit question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n$ converges. Prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_1+2u_2 +...+nu_n}{n} = 0$$

My solution is as such:

$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n}{n}\leq\frac{u_1+u_2 +\dots+u_n}{n}\leq\frac{u_1+2u_2 +\dots+nu_n}{n}\leq\frac{nu_1+nu_2 +\dots+nu_n}{n}=u_n$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n}{n} = 0$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n = c$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$

and $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n = 0$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n$ converges converges.

By squeeze theorem, 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_1+2u_2 +...+nu_n}{n}$ exists and is equal to 0.

Is that correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct when $u_n\ge 0$

Comment: Watch the last step in your chain: $$\frac{nu_1 + nu_2 + \cdots + nu_n}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i$$

Comment: $\frac{nu_1+\ldots +nu_n}{n}=u_1+\ldots +u_n\ne u_n$

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of Kronecker's lemma which states that
if $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an infinite sequence of real numbers such that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n
$$
exists and is finite, then we have for $0<b_1\leq b_2 \leq b_3 \leq \ldots$ and $b_n \to \infty$ that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n b_ku_k = 0.
$$

(you can find the statement and the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma)).

In our case, $b_n=n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n$$
then since
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$
we have
$$\frac{u_1+2u_2+\cdots+nu_n}{n^2}-\frac\ell2\sim_\infty\frac1{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk(u_k-\ell)\right)=:w_n$$
and we have
$$|w_n|\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n|u_k-\ell|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\ 0 \;\;\text{using Cesàro theorem}$$
so we conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_1+2u_2+\cdots+nu_n}{n^2}=\frac\ell2$$

Comment: Is it somehow possible to get the normal text style inside $$ to resolve the "à" problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the summation by parts formula:
$$
u_k = a_k - a_{k-1}, a_0 = 0
\\
\sum_{k=1}^n u_kb_k = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - a_{k-1})b_k = 
a_n b_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k(b_k - b_{k+1})
$$

details:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n u_kk = a_n  n
-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k
$$Using the Cesaro theorem:
$$
a_n\to \sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k = S
\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k
=n S + o(n)
$$you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n u_kk =
\left(S + o(1)\right) \times n
 -n S + o(n) = o(n)
$$